# QPX Express API: Why Ryanair is missing?

Tags: google-api

is there a specific reason why Ryanair is missing from the QPX Express API results while it appears in a normal search on Google Flight?
Thanks

Max

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not to do with programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question for QPX Express.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the QPX API and Ita Software Matrix (by Google) gives the same results, not including a lot of companies like Ryanair.

I asked Google Support about it.

The answer is:

"***QPX Express API and Matrix only include fares that are filed with ATPCO.  There are a number of small carriers and low cost carriers that do not file.***"

Asking Google if they consider to add these flights to their APIs the answer was:

"***Airlines determine which distribution channel they want to participate in.  If any of these airlines were to file with ATPCO, then we would certainly be interested.***"